# Fluent validation on Enumeration when type is nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Trying to validate a value falls in between the min and max values of an enumeration using fluent validators.

This is done like this

```
 public static class EnumerationValidatorExtensions
    {
        public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int> MustBeValidEnumerationTypeId<T, TEnumeration>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int> ruleBuilder)
            where TEnumeration : Enumeration
        {
            var enumerationTypes = Enumeration.GetAllStaticDeclaredPropertyValues<TEnumeration>();
            var enumerationTypeIds = enumerationTypes.Keys;
            var min = enumerationTypeIds.Min();
            var max = enumerationTypeIds.Max();

            return ruleBuilder.InclusiveBetween(min, max);
        }
    }
```

Then I can call this like this

```
   RuleFor(session => session.SinglesScoringFormatTypeId)
                .MustBeValidEnumerationTypeId<SessionCreateRequest, ScoringFormatTypes>()
```

Problem arises when the SinglesScoringFormatTypeId is a nullable int.

How can use rule builder to accept a nullable int and throw an error when the value is actually null ?

I can change the method signature to take nullable int like this

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int?> MustBeValidEnumerationTypeId<T, TEnumeration>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int?> ruleBuilder)
            where TEnumeration : Enumeration
        {
```

How can I access the passed int and make sure its null ?

Comment: Using `int?` doesn't work?

Comment: Of course I can change the signature to this
 public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int?> MustBeValidEnumerationTypeId<T, TEnumeration>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int?> ruleBuilder)
            where TEnumeration : Enumeration
        {
But how can I tell if the passed in value is null ?

Comment: Does this work? https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#notnull-validator

Comment: Of course this is valid as a notnul validation. I am trying to make sure a passed in int is not null using the IRuleBuilderOptions

Comment: Excuse me that I rarely use FluentValidation, but doesn't `return ruleBuilder.NotNull().InclusiveBetween(min, max);` work?